# Visualizing Y-gate operation to achieve quantum state

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state, pauli-gates

In the below snippet how qc.y(1) helps to achieve the quantum state $i|10\rangle$ ?

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit,
execute, Aer   
qc= QuantumCircuit(2,2)   
qc.y(1)
```

I understand,
Applying Y-gate to the qubit 1 will put in $i|1\rangle$state and qubit 0 will be in $|0\rangle$ state.
The resultant tensor-product will be $i|10\rangle$

But trying to Visualize in matrix form.

Answer (score 3):

In Qiskit, you can easily get the matrix of any quantum circuit as follows:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex

op = Operator(qc)
array_to_latex(op.data)
```

The output:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & - i & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & - i  \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & i & 0 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your initial state is two qubits in state 0, i.e. $|00\rangle = |0\rangle_{\#1}|0\rangle_{\#0} = |0\rangle_{\#1} \otimes |0\rangle_{\#0}$ (subscript indicates qubit1 and qubit0.)

Now, you are applying $Y$ to your qubit1, and you are doing nothing to qubit0. Doing nothing is equivalent to multiplying by the identity matrix. So your operation is as follows.

$$
|00\rangle \rightarrow Y_{\#1} \otimes I_{\#0}|00\rangle
$$

Evaluating this,

$
\begin{align}
Y \otimes I|00\rangle &= (Y \otimes I)(|0\rangle_{\#1}\otimes|0\rangle_{\#0})\\
&= Y|0\rangle_{\#1} \otimes I|0\rangle_{\#0} \\
&= i|1\rangle_{\#1} \otimes |0\rangle_{\#0} \\
& = i |10\rangle
\end{align}
$

Try following these equations by multiplying explicitly using matrices and vectors; where

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -i\\
i & 0
\end{bmatrix} ;|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$